# UI tools to view hibernate second level cache data

Tags: java, hibernate, caching, hazelcast

Do we have any tool which I can use to view Hibernate Second level cache data object.
I have used Jconsole ,visualvm and hazelcast mancenter but I donot see this feature in any of this tool.

My main aim is to what data are cache and I want check how read/write and transactional caching works.

Just want make everything is working fine in my application.

I was wondering how people test read/write and transaction caching,how do they make sure everything will work perfectly fine in prod in env.

Comment: Do you use `com.hazelcast.hibernate.HazelcastCacheRegionFactory` or `com.hazelcast.hibernate.HazelcastLocalCacheRegionFactory` as your `hibernate.cache.region.factory_class`?

Comment: currently HazelcastCacheRegionFactory  is used

Answer (score 0):

When `com.hazelcast.hibernate.HazelcastCacheRegionFactory` is used, all data is stored in a Hazelcast IMap. Data stored in a Hazelcast IMap can be browsed by using the [Map Browser on Hazelcast Management Center](http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.8.1/manual/html-single/index.html#map-browser). Unfortunately, the Map Browser currently supports only browsing the entries that have a String/Integer/Long key.

We plan on adding better browsing capabilities to Management Center in the future versions. Until then, your best option seems to be having a little utility program which queries and shows data stored in the Hazelcast IMap.

Comment: is Map browser available in 3.1.3 developer version mancenter as I donot see any map browser in current version sometime it appears but not available every time

Comment: I see it's available in the source code. I don't know about version 3.1.3 but in the later versions (like 3.7 onwards), there's no problem related to Map browser not being available. I would advise using the latest version which is version 3.8.1 at the moment. This way, you'll be able to use the enhanced map browser when we add it and also take advantage of the new features that are added in the meantime.

Comment: I'm using Hazelcast 3.9.4 and Mancenter 3.10.3 and I still cannot see the Maps that back the Hibernate second-level cache.  Sure would be nice to be able to see this.  I can see the Topics associated with each cache, however.

Comment: It means you're using https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-hibernate#hazelcastlocalcacheregionfactory which has no distributed maps holding any data, only local maps. If you want to be able to browse the data, you need to use this: https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-hibernate#hazelcastlocalcacheregionfactory